# Using BufferedReader and DataInputStream in harmony

Tags: java, image, sockets, bufferedreader, datainputstream

I've been poking around the internet for quite a while now, and I was wondering how I could use BufferedReader and DataInputStream together without opening a different port. I've tried to stream images, but as the buffered reader stores extra bytes, it creates a corrupt image. When I attempt to use DataInputStream.read(), I can't read full lines of text as easily. Is there some sort of solution for my problem?

Comment: `BufferedReader`s are for textual input. Did you mean `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: I'm trying to read text as well as data.

Comment: I suggest you not mix test reader/writers with binary.  Instead send text as binary data with readUTF/writeUTF or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataInputStream.readLine(), and yes I know it's deprecated. The real solution is not to use lines in your protocol. Use readUTF() for example.